# Jlist and NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlist

I am working on this thing for class, and I have been having a ton of trouble with Jlists. I thought I finally figured out how to update them with list data models, but it still doesn't work.

Please help.

**Class causing me trouble:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class ClubDriverWindow extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private ArrayList playerList;
    private DefaultListModel playerListModel;

    private String[] secondPlayerItems = new String[1];
    private String[] firstPlayerItems = new String[1];
    private String[] players1Items = new String[1];
    private String[] players2Items = new String[1];
    private String[] retirePlayerItems = new String[1];
    private String[] jcomp12Items = new String[1];
    private String[] restorePlayerItems = new String[1];

    private JTextArea players;
    private JComboBox secondPlayer;
    private JComboBox firstPlayer;
    private JButton player1Win;
    private JButton player2wins;
    private JButton draw;
    private JButton exit;
    private JComboBox players1;
    private JComboBox players2;
    private JTextArea jcomp10;
    private JComboBox retirePlayer;
    private JList jcomp12;
    private JComboBox restorePlayer;
    private JButton retireButton;
    private JButton restoreButton;
    private JTextArea jcomp16;
    private JTextField addPlayer;
    private JButton addButton;

    public ClubDriverWindow() {
        playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
        Player starter = new Player ("Starter");
        playerList.add(starter);
        playerList.add(starter);
        playerList.add(starter);
        playerList.add(starter);
        playerList.add(starter);
        playerListModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();

        updatePlayers();

        //construct components
        players = new JTextArea (5, 5);
        secondPlayer = new JComboBox (secondPlayerItems);
        secondPlayer.addActionListener(this); 
        secondPlayer.setActionCommand("secondPlayerComboBox");
        firstPlayer = new JComboBox (firstPlayerItems);
        player1Win = new JButton ("Win");
        player2wins = new JButton ("Win");
        draw = new JButton ("Draw");
        exit = new JButton ("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(this);;
        exit.setActionCommand("exit");
        players1 = new JComboBox (players1Items);
        players2 = new JComboBox (players2Items);
        jcomp10 = new JTextArea (5, 5);
        retirePlayer = new JComboBox (retirePlayerItems);
        jcomp12 = new JList (playerListModel);
        restorePlayer = new JComboBox (restorePlayerItems);
        retireButton = new JButton ("Retire");
        restoreButton = new JButton ("Restore");
        jcomp16 = new JTextArea (5, 5);
        addPlayer = new JTextField (5);
        addButton = new JButton ("Add Player");
        addButton.addActionListener(this);
        addButton.setActionCommand("addPlayer");

        //set components properties
        players.setToolTipText ("This is a leaderboard of players");
        secondPlayer.setToolTipText ("Choose a Player");
        firstPlayer.setToolTipText ("Choose a player");
        player1Win.setToolTipText ("Player 1 wins");
        player2wins.setToolTipText ("Player2 Wins");
        draw.setToolTipText ("No victor");
        exit.setToolTipText ("Help, I am trapped in a JButton!");
        players1.setToolTipText ("Choose a Player");
        players2.setToolTipText ("Choose a Player");
        retirePlayer.setToolTipText ("CHoose a Player");
        restorePlayer.setToolTipText ("Choose a player");
        retireButton.setToolTipText ("Set a player aside (for now)");
        restoreButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to bring a player back");
        addButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to add a new player");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (784, 508));
        setLayout (null);

        //add components
        add (players);
        add (secondPlayer);
        add (firstPlayer);
        add (player1Win);
        add (player2wins);
        add (draw);
        add (exit);
        add (players1);
        add (players2);
        add (jcomp10);
        add (retirePlayer);
        add (jcomp12);
        add (restorePlayer);
        add (retireButton);
        add (restoreButton);
        add (jcomp16);
        add (addPlayer);
        add (addButton);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        players.setBounds (40, 40, 300, 300);
        secondPlayer.setBounds (-170, 295, 100, 75);
        firstPlayer.setBounds (-185, 355, 100, 75);
        player1Win.setBounds (45, 405, 100, 25);
        player2wins.setBounds (215, 405, 100, 25);
        draw.setBounds (135, 445, 100, 25);
        exit.setBounds (675, 5, 100, 25);
        players1.setBounds (45, 365, 100, 25);
        players2.setBounds (215, 365, 100, 25);
        jcomp10.setBounds (380, 0, 2, 600);
        retirePlayer.setBounds (415, 60, 100, 25);
        jcomp12.setBounds (-150, 345, 100, 75);
        restorePlayer.setBounds (415, 110, 100, 25);
        retireButton.setBounds (595, 60, 100, 25);
        restoreButton.setBounds (595, 110, 100, 25);
        jcomp16.setBounds (-150, 300, 100, 75);
        addPlayer.setBounds (415, 165, 100, 25);
        addButton.setBounds (595, 165, 100, 25);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("MyPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new ClubDriverWindow());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }

    public void wonGame(Player winner, Player loser){
        double wRating = winner.getRating();
        double lRating = loser.getRating();
        double pointModifier = (lRating/wRating);
        wRating += ((pointModifier*10)+0.5);
        lRating -= ((pointModifier*10)-0.5);
        winner.setRating(wRating);
        loser.setRating(lRating);
        winner.setWins(winner.getWins() + 1);
        loser.setLosses(winner.getLosses() + 1);
    }

    public void drawGame(Player player1, Player player2){
        double p1Rating = player1.getRating();
        double p2Rating = player2.getRating();
        double p1modifier = ((p1Rating-p2Rating)/p1Rating);
        double p2modifier = ((p2Rating-p1Rating)/p2Rating);
        p1Rating += ((p1modifier*-5));
        p2Rating += ((p2modifier*-5));
        player1.setRating(p1Rating);
        player2.setRating(p2Rating);
        player1.setDraws(player1.getDraws() + 1);
        player2.setDraws(player2.getDraws() + 1);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("secondPlayerComboBox")){
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("exit")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("addPlayer")){
            addNewPlayer();
        }
    }

    public void addNewPlayer(){

    }

    public void updatePlayers(){
        int size = playerList.size();
        playerListModel.clear();
        for (int j = 0; (j < (size-1)); j++){
            playerListModel.add(j,((Player)playerList.get(j)).getName());
        }
        jcomp12.setModel(playerListModel);
    }
}
```

**Related Player class:**

```
public class Player
{
    //private Record playerRecord
    private double rating;
    private final String ID = "";
    private int ranking;
    public String name;
    private int losses;
    private int wins;
    private int draws;

    public Player(String name){
        rating = 1000.0;
        ranking = 0;
        name = name;
        losses = 0;
        wins = 0;
        draws = 0;
    }

    int getTotalGames(){
        int t = (wins+draws+losses);
        return t;
    }

    float getWinLossRatio(){
        float r = (wins/losses);
        return r;
    }

    int getWins(){
        return wins;
    }

    int getLosses(){
        return losses;
    }

    int getDraws(){
        return draws;
    }

    double getRating(){
        return rating;
    }

    String getID(){
        return ID ;
    }

    double getRanking(){
        return ranking;
    }

    String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    void setWins(int newWins){
        wins = newWins;
    }

    void setLosses(int newLosses){
        losses = newLosses;
    }

    void setDraws(int newDraws){
        draws = newDraws;
    }

    void setRating(double newRating){
        rating = newRating;
    }

    void setName(String newName){
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ClubDriverWindow.updatePlayers(ClubDriverWindow.java:194)
    at ClubDriverWindow.<init>(ClubDriverWindow.java:52)
    at ClubDriverWindow.main(ClubDriverWindow.java:144)
```

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: Run this through a debugger.. it will be really easy to see the problem. Any IDE has one.

Comment: I have compiled it, and it compiles fine, and only has the error when I run it.  I am using BlueJ, which is, in my opinion, a terrible IDE, and I can't find the debug button on it...  I am still looking

Comment: You are assigning the name value to itself in the Player class "name = name;", therefore, it's null, that's one problem

Comment: @BlueGoldStar Eclipse or Intellij are much better options for IDEs. Debuggers are your best friend.

Comment: I assume you mean that name is used twice in the Player constructer.  I just changed that, and it still will not run.  Thank you anyway

Comment: @LeBarton I know, but we have to use BlueJ for class, it really bugs me (no pun intended).  My teacher won't take assignments made on eclipse, which is is my favorite Java IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should change

```
private ArrayList playerList;
private DefaultListModel playerListModel;
```

to

```
private ArrayList<Player> playerList;
private DefaultListModel<String> playerListModel;
```

And for this part,

```
Player starter = new Player ("Starter");
playerList.add(starter);
playerList.add(starter);
playerList.add(starter);
playerList.add(starter);
playerList.add(starter);
```

If you want 5 different `Players`, you will need to create them one by one, e.g.

```
Player starter = null;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    starter = new Player("Starter" + i);
    playerList.add(starter);
}
```

**Ok, this is where the `NullPointerException` part is answered.**

For your `NullPointerException`, you need to call `updatePlayers();` after you have initialized `jcomp12`..

```
 jcomp12 = new JList (playerListModel);
 // ....
 updatePlayers();
```

or jcomp12 will be null inside the `updatePlayers()` method!

Comment: I think you just fixed it, thank you so, so much.  I have been working on this for the past 6 hours.  Now I just feel like an idiot...  Seriously though, thank you!

Comment: No problem, made such mistakes myself. I know how it feels like. :)